# Looking for an answer on a fallacy or debate tactic to discredit the other person

Tags: fallacies, argumentation, debate, cognitive-bias

I am trying to find out what it is called when you disagree with a certain group on the status, tactics, view, etc so they call you exactly what they are against just to discredit your viewpoint. Even if you aren't actually what they say you are.

Example:

Person A - I do not agree with your ideas on fighting racism.

Person B - Well then you are racist and are part of the problem.

That's just the example that came to my mind first.

It is solely to discredit your viewpoint and shuts out any option for conversation or opposing viewpoint on how things should be. There is no proof of their claim to degrade your character and is used to automatically discredits any critiques you may have or removes you from the conversation completely.

This is not meant to be about racism exactly, it's just the first thing that came to mind to show as an example.

Comment: It's sort of an ad hominem.  The subtext is that racism as a position is incorrect - you hold a position that is incorrect, therefore you are incorrect.  That's not quite the same as an ad hominem that is purely unrelated to the argument.  We may compare it to one person dismissing another person as a "solipsist" - if they are a solipsist, and if there are legitimate reasons to disbelieve solipsism, then this would be a valid criticism of their position and not an ad hominem fallacy.  But it may be an unfair label.

Comment: If you want to actually debate someone in philosophy, it is required that both people agree on the same spirit of debate:  that they will hear each other's views and honestly try to understand them, and ask and answer questions to clarify things in a Socratic way, and try to keep things on a friendly basis even while disagreeing.  There has to be an element of cooperation.  If these criteria are not met - which is usually - and it starts feeling like an ego battle, or a battle of your tribe against his tribe, then there's no purpose in the discussion and you should leave it.

Comment: Perhaps it's more accurate to call it a strawman than an ad hominem, because they are reducing your position to "racism" which is easy to refute, which may not be fair.

Comment: [You are either with us, or against us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_are_either_with_us,_or_against_us#Historical_quotations). "The statement generally is a descriptive statement identifying the beliefs of the speakers, and thus states a basic assumption, not a logical conclusion... Sometimes it is interpreted as a splitting or a false dilemma, which is an informal fallacy. Some see the statement as a way of persuading others to choose sides in a conflict which does not allow the position of neutrality."

Comment: [Fallacy of Opposition](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Fallacy-of-Opposition):"Asserting that those who disagree with you must be wrong and not thinking straight". [*Ergo decedo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergo_decedo):"responding to the criticism of a critic by implying that the critic is motivated by undisclosed favorability or affiliation to an out-group, rather than responding to the criticism itself."